# How to create a custom theme in drupal6 and apply template to it

Tags: php, drupal-6, drupal-modules, drupal-theming

I am just tried to create a module name `mymodule` and tried to apply theme to that module in drupal6.

I have added .info file for my module and created `mymodule.tpl.php` file in my theme folder and enable the module from the admin. But when i access the module through url it returns white page.

My mymodule.module.php file contains

```
function mymodule_menu() {
  $items = array();

  $items['mymodule'] = array(
    'page callback' => 'mymodule_page',
    'access arguments' => array('access content'),
    'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,
  );

  return $items;
}

function mymodule_page() {
  $result = db_query('SELECT * from node');
  return theme('mymodule', array('output' => $result));
}

function mymodule_theme() { 
  $content =  array(
    'custom' => array(
      'arguments' => array('output' => 'NULL'),
       'template' =>  path_to_theme() . '/mymodule',
      'path' => '/'
     ),
  );
  return $content;
}
```

I don't know why the theme is not applying to my module. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For what I see the problems are the `path` and `template` keys.

From Drupal docs ( http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer%21hooks%21core.php/function/hook_theme/6 ):

> path: Override the path of the file to be used. Ordinarily the module
>   or theme path will be used, but if the file will not be in the default
>   path, include it here. This path should be relative to the Drupal root
>   directory.

So you're overriding the module path with `/`, which should result in the Drupal root folder ( in which there is no mymodule.tpl.php ). Try removing the `path` key.

Also, the `template` key should be only the **template** file name. Docs:

> template: If specified, this theme implementation is a template, and
>   this is the template file without an extension.

So try removing the `path_to_theme` part, as you have to give the template file name and not the full path to the template ( which you are providing using the `path_to_theme` function ).

Hope this will help!

Comment: Yah its worked for me. Currently i can only able to view this in content area of page.tpl.php. How can i change the entire template for a theme? This question i have added here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16609463/how-can-i-change-the-entire-template-of-the-page-according-to-module-in-drupal6