# how can i change the entire template of the page according to module in drupal6

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-6

I have check lots of area in the web about theming in drupal6. All the tutorials in the web saying theme module, which means the theming a small area or theming a samll blobk etc. But in my case i need to change the entire template of a page when i access a module. Is this is possible in `drupal6`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write if conditions in your theme's template.php function.
The function is `template_preprocess_page(&$variables)`

And in this function, write some if conditions.

```
For example:
if($some_condition) {
  $suggestions[] = 'YOUR_CUSTOM_TEMPLATE';
}
$variables['template_files'] = $suggestions;
```

And you will have your template "YOUR_CUSTOM_TEMPLATE.tpl.php".
Which should be there in theme's templates directory.

Also, you can have a custom template for a content type.
e.g. For a content type student, the template will be:

```
page--student.tpl.php
```

Comment: But how can i check the current module is this?

Answer (score 0):

Got from Drupal Answers ( https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/18670 ) :

> **How can I create a custom page with a different template?**
>
> You can use a different template for a page by suggesting a new
>   template file that will be used.
>
> This can be done in a theme, by writing its
>   [template_preprocess_page](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!theme.inc/function/template_preprocess_page/6)(), or in a module by implementing
>   hook_preprocess_page().
>   In the case you are using it in a module, template_preprocess_page() needs to be
>   renamed mymodule_preprocess_page(), where "mymodule" is the short name of your module.

```
function mymodule_preprocess_page(&$variables) {
  if (arg(0) == "node" && arg(1) == "1") {
    array_unshift($variables['theme_hook_suggestions'], "page--custom-template");
  }
}
```